# ReturnType of curried function

Tags: typescript, generics, types, currying

Using `ReturnType<T>` in a function returns, as you would expect, the return type.

```
type F = () => string
//ReturnType<F> === string
```

Also, as you would expect, when using curried functions the return type is

```
type FF = () => () => string
//ReturnType<FF> === () => string
```

Is there a way to create a generic type that returns the final return? I.E

```
type FF = () => () => string
//FinalReturnType<FF> === string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This currently works (TS 3.7), but the TS team didn’t intentionally allow it and hasn’t decided to support it. It may break in future versions.

```
type FinalReturnType<T> = {
  0: T,
  1: T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? FinalReturnType<R> : T,
}[T extends (...args: any) => infer _ ? 1 : 0];
```

It has to be this strange and ugly because there's currently a restriction that says a type can only call itself if it's nested inside another structural type (in this case, an object with two keys), but then we immediately pull the property we need from the tuple.

**How it would ideally look:**

If the language supported this kind of mechanism, I'd think it would be as simple as:

```
type FinalReturnType<T> = T extends (...args: any) => infer R
                              ? FinalReturnType<R> 
                              : T;
```

In other words, use a recursive definition. If `T` is a function, it calls itself passing the return type of the function. If not a function, it returns `T` itself. So for example:

```
FinalReturnType<string> // -> string
```

And so that terminates the recursion: when you've unwrapped all the layers of functions that return functions, you eventually reach a non-function.

Unfortunately, this isn't possible, producing the error:

```
Type alias 'FinalReturnType' circularly references itself.
```

There was a [change to enable recursive type references](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33050) but it doesn't enable this scenario.

There is [an open discussion of more general support for recursion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980).

The present situation is that you can only compile my answer if you add `[]` around the self-call to make it a tuple:

```
type FinalReturnType<T> = T extends (...args: any) => infer R
                                ? [FinalReturnType<R>] 
    : T;

type t1 = FinalReturnType<string>;  // -> string

type F = () => string
type t2 = FinalReturnType<F>;       // -> [string]

type FF = () => () => string
type t3 = FinalReturnType<FF>;      // -> [[string]]
```

As you can see, this re-wraps the results in layers of nested tuples, and you're back to the same problem, because you can't unwrap those either.

Currently you can currently use the trick of wrapping in an object with two properties, then immediately unwrapping by indexing the right one, as described at the top of this answer. But this was enabled by accident, and the TS team aren’t sure whether they want to support/encourage this.

Comment: The discussion describes the workaround and a warning that it's [not supported](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980#issuecomment-566152178).  I'd avoid recommending this for any production code that needs to keep working. Instead I'd usually write an ugly type that specifically only supports some fixed recursion depth, such as, say 5.  (In this case you'd have `type FinalReturnType<T> = ...FRT0<T>...`, `type FRT0<T> = ...FRT1<T>...`, all the way to `type FRT5<T> = ....` where the last one just bails out.) I wish recursive conditional types were supported, but they aren't.

Comment: @jcalz thanks for the clarification, have added prominent disclaimer.

Comment: Looks like official support for recursive types is on the way: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40002